# How to handle click of weblinks within a textual content set to a TextView

Tags: android

I am working on chat project. For showing chat messages I am using the following layout

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/messageText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    tools:text="hello hello hello hello" />
```

And on java side, I am simply formatted the message text and then set it to the TextView.

**I am facing 2 main issues:**

1. When I click on weblink in the message, screen scrolls either top or bottom. This does not happen when I click the non-weblink portion of the message.
2. Click doesn't navigate to the corresponding webpage. With too much difficulty, sometimes it happens that I am able to navigate to the webpage.

**Things I have tried:**

- I tried using the `setMovementMethod(context)` method after setting the text but didn't work.
- I also tried things like removing the `autoLink="web"` from layout as suggested by some.
- I also tried `setLinksClickable(true)` and `setAutoMask(0)` but nothing is working.

I have spent quite some time on it now. Can someone help me here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use an inherited class from `ClickableSpan`, as such `setLinksClickable` `TextView`'s method is not enough, each link in the text assigned to `TextView` must have the click event.

The solution is coded in Xamarin, but i thinks is easily translatable to Java.

With this function, we check de html string text, and we get the links and make each of them clickable with `MakeLinkClickable` function.

```
public static void SetTextAsHtmlWithOverrideLinks(Android.Widget.TextView textview, string text)
{
     var sequence = text.GetTextAsHtml();

    var strBuilder = new Android.Text.SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
    var urls = strBuilder.GetSpans(0, sequence.Length(), Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(Android.Text.Style.URLSpan)));

    foreach (Android.Text.Style.URLSpan span in urls) {
        MakeLinkClickable(strBuilder, span);
    }

    textview.MovementMethod = Android.Text.Method.LinkMovementMethod.Instance;
    textview.TextFormatted = strBuilder;
}
```

This function makes each link clickable with `LinkSpan` class, which has our action on link click

```
public static void MakeLinkClickable(Android.Text.SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder, Android.Text.Style.URLSpan span)
{
    strBuilder.SetSpan(new LinkSpan(span), strBuilder.GetSpanStart(span), strBuilder.GetSpanEnd(span),strBuilder.GetSpanFlags(span));
    strBuilder.RemoveSpan(span);
}

public class LinkSpan : Android.Text.Style.ClickableSpan
{
    public Android.Text.Style.URLSpan Link { get; }

    public LinkSpan(Android.Text.Style.URLSpan span) {
        Link = span;
    }

    public override void OnClick(Android.Views.View widget)
    {
        if (widget is Android.Widget.TextView textView)
            // Here open url or another action with your own method;

        widget.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

This function converts our html text to a spannable text to handle it.

```
public static Android.Text.ISpanned GetTextAsHtml(this string input)
{
    if (input == null)
        input = string.Empty;

    if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.N)
        return Android.Text.Html.FromHtml(input,Android.Text.FromHtmlOptions.ModeLegacy);
    else
        return Android.Text.Html.FromHtml(input);
}
```

Use:

```
SetTextAsHtmlWithOverrideLinks(yourtextView, theHTMLTextString);
```

Comment: Thank you Ollie, I get the idea. I will try this solution.

Comment: So I implemented the idea in android it worked. But there is one problem. I don't know why but when I tap on the message text, screen scrolls a little bit either to upside or downside. Not able to figure out what might be causing this @Ollie Strevel

Comment: If this works for you original answer, mark it as the right answer, so other users can find this useful.